# Extract the 'image' attribute from this chunk of text via regex

Tags: php, regex

I can find many examples of finding URL's withing HTML, however, I need to be more specific and extract the URL for the image in the following piece of text:

I will only need the first match.

I am using PHP.

Expected value result: http://cdn.somewebsite.com/path/123.jpg

```
var flashvars = {
'url_mode':'1',
'image':'http://cdn.somewebsite.com/path/123.jpg',
'bufferlength':'3',
'id': 'player',
'autostart': 'true'
...
};
```

Comment: ok, and you tried to solve this how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with positive lookbehind assertion:

```
$data = <<< EOF
var flashvars = {
'url_mode':'1',
'image':'http://cdn.somewebsite.com/path/123.jpg',
'bufferlength':'3',
'id': 'player',
'autostart': 'true'
...
};
EOF;

preg_match("/(?<='image':')[^']+/", $data, $match);
echo($match[0]);
```

Comment: See http://ideone.com/Ww8ylb

Answer (score 0):

Hi this should work for you.

preg_match(/http.*?\.jpg/)